# Previous day date in unix shell script

Tags: shell, date, unix

I want to a declare a variable called val1 holding the date of the previous day in yyyymmdd format

Any help would be great

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
val1=$(date +%Y%m%d --date="yesterday")
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use GNU date command as shown below**

> Getting Date In the Past
>
> To get yesterday and earlier day in the past use string day ago:

date --date='yesterday'

date --date='1 day ago'

date --date='10 day ago'

date --date='10 week ago'

date --date='10 month ago'

date --date='10 year ago'

> Getting Date In the Future
>
> To get tomorrow and day after tomorrow (tomorrow+N) use day word to get date in the future as follows:

date --date='tomorrow'

date --date='1 day'

date --date='10 day'

date --date='10 week'

date --date='10 month'

date --date='10 year'

In this case it should be

val1=`date +%Y%m%d --date="yesterday"`

Answer (score 0):

If your `date` implemention chokes on @user2042297's answer, this *might* work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    split(strftime("%Y %m %d", systime()), now)
    yesterday = mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0", now[1], now[2], now[3]-1))
    print strftime("%Y%m%d", yesterday)
}'
```

This may require GNU awk, so you might not be in a better position.