# Create a Shell Script for Uploading Previous Data Backup via cronjob On linux

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3

I have a backup file which created every night at 23:59. now i want a script to upload the file to s3 on the next day..
i have created a script but its not running as its saying that you don't have any file for current day.
below is the script i created...

```
#!/bin/bash

 FILENAME1="file.log.`date +%Y-%m-%d`"
 FILENAME2="file2.log.`date +%Y-%m-%d `.gz"
 BUCKET="file-logs"
 SAVEDIR="/home/ubuntu/logs"



 sudo  gzip -k ${SAVEDIR}/${FILENAME1}
 if [ -e ${SAVEDIR}/${FILENAME1} ]; then

    # Upload to AWS
    aws s3 cp ${SAVEDIR}/${FILENAME2} s3://${BUCKET}

    # Test result of last command run
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
        echo "Upload to AWS failed"
        exit 1
    fi

    # If success, remove backup file
    # sudo  rm ${SAVEDIR}/${FILENAME1}

    # Exit with no error
    #exit 0
  fi
```

If anyone could help me out here..as i'm not too familiar with shell-script &  all.

Comment: Can you provide full error message?

Comment: Did you check "gzip" succeeded? My machine throws error for `-k` option for gzip.

Comment: I'd advise you to add `else` clauses in the `if`-loops, and make sure that error messages are redirected to a file, which you can follow, either by launching the file by hand either by launching it over the cron.

Comment: @Marcin this is the full error i'm getting
gzip: /home/ubuntu/logs/file.log.2020-06-01: No such file or directory

Comment: @Fazlin  yes gzip -k is working for me

Comment: Does the file `/home/ubuntu/logs/file.log.2020-06-01` really exist? What is the output of `ls /home/ubuntu/logs/file.log.2020-06-01`?

Comment: How is `file.log.<date>` getting renamed to `file2.log.<date>` ?

Comment: @1dmahesh : Since your script is running **very** close to midnight, the effect will vary depending on whether `date` is called before or after midnight. Instead of recalculating the date twice (another source for errors), I would calculate the date once at the beginning, by `DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`, and then just use this variable.  I also would print the `$DATE` in your error messages, so that we know which date has actually be used.

Comment: @Fazlin The file will get created at 23:59 in the night..

Comment: @WayneVosberg I'm using gzip to create the zip file with the different name & extension that is  `file2.log.<date>.gz`.

Comment: @user1934428 very well said. but the  problem is that i want the file1 to get backed up on the next day so what should i use instead of `DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)` .
because this variable is backing up for the current day only.
not for the previous day which i want....!

Comment: Quick fix: could you start the job 1 minute past midnight so it is the same day?

Comment: @1dmahesh : If you need the file for the previous day, you have to [calculate the previous day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333549/previous-day-date-in-unix-shell-script).

Comment: @user1934428 yes .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can ask date to format any date instead of "now" using `--date` so you could ask it to format `date +%Y-%m-%d --date=yesterday`